# C/Fortran hybrid code using MPI/ScaLAPACK seg faults in a weird way

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fortran, mpi, scalapack

I am trying to translate this [CODE](http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/explore-html/de/d37/pdgbdriver_8f_source.html) from Fortran into C.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "mpi.h"

#define PRINT_NOTHING             0
#define PRINT_UP_TO_MESGS         1
#define PRINT_UP_TO_ARRAYS        2
#define PRINT_UP_TO_MATRICES      3
#define PRINT_LEVEL               PRINT_UP_TO_MATRICES

/*! Parameters: */
#define TOTMEM                    425053208
#define INTMEM                    13107200
#define NTESTS                    20
#define DLEN_                     9
#define DBLESZ                    8               /*! Size of a DOUBLE PRE. */
#define MEMSIZ                    425053208/8     /*! Memory for DOUBLE PRE. */

#define MASTER                    0
#define MPI_ERROR_CODE_ERROR_GRID 1
#define MPI_ERROR_CODE_NOT_FACT   2
#define MPI_ERROR_CODE_NOT_SOLVE  3

#define BLACS_USER_WONT_FIN_MPI   0
#define BLACS_USER_WILL_FIN_MPI   1

#define DESCRIPTOR_SIZE           7

typedef enum {
  FALSE,
  TRUE
  
} logical;

/*! External subroutines: */
extern void Cblacs_barrier  (int context,
                             char* scope);
extern void Cblacs_exit     (int doneflag);
extern void Cblacs_get      (int ,
                             int ,
                             int *context);
extern void Cblacs_gridexit (int context);
extern void Cblacs_gridinfo (int context,
                             int *our_nprow,
                             int *our_npcol,
                             int *my_prow,
                             int *my_pcol);
extern void Cblacs_gridinit (int* context,
                             char* order,
                             int nproc_rows,
                             int nproc_cols);
extern void Cblacs_pinfo    (int *my_blacs_pid,
                             int *our_blacs_nprocs);

/* http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/explore-html/dd/d22/descinit_8f.html */
extern void descinit_       (int *desc,
                             int *m,
                             int *n,
                             int *mb,
                             int *nb,
                             int *irsrc,
                             int *icsrc,
                             int *ictxt,
                             int *lld,
                             int *info);
/* http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/explore-html/dc/d44/igsum2d___8c.html */
extern void igsum2d_        (int *contxt,
                             char *scope,
                             char *top,
                             int *m,
                             int *n,
                             int *a,
                             int *lda,
                             int *rdest,
                             int *cdest);
/* http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/explore-html/db/da1/pdbmatgen_8f.html */
extern void pdbmatgen_      (int *ictxt,
                             char *aform,
                             char *aform2,
                             int *bwl,
                             int *bwu,
                             int *n,
                             int *mb,
                             int *nb,
                             double *a,
                             int *lda,
                             int *iarow,
                             int *iacol,
                             int *iseed,
                             int *myrow,
                             int *mycol,
                             int *nprow,
                             int *npcol);
/* http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/explore-html/d8/dba/pdchekpad_8f.html */
extern void pdchekpad_      (int * ictxt,
                             char *mess,
                             int *m,
                             int *n,
                             double *a,
                             int *lda,
                             int *ipre,
                             int *ipost,
                             double *chkval);
/* http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/explore-html/d2/dc2/pddblaschk_8f.html */
extern void pddblaschk_     (char *symm,
                             char *uplo,
                             char *trans,
                             int *n,
                             int *bwl,
                             int *bwu,
                             int *nrhs,
                             double *x,
                             int *ix,
                             int *jx,
                             int *descx,
                             int *iaseed,
                             double *a,
                             int *ia,
                             int *ja,
                             int *desca,
                             int *ibseed,
                             double *anorm,
                             double *resid,
                             double *work,
                             int *worksiz);
/* http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/explore-html/d6/d3b/pdfillpad_8f.html */
extern void pdfillpad_      (int *ictxt,
                             int *m,
                             int *n,
                             double *a,
                             int *lda,
                             int *ipre,
                             int *ipost,
                             double *chkval);
/* http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/explore-html/d0/d2b/pdgbinfo_8f.html */
extern void pdgbinfo_       (char *summry,
                             int *nout,
                             char *trans,
                             int *nmat,
                             int *nval,
                             int *ldnval,
                             int *nbw,
                             int *bwlval,
                             int *bwuval,
                             int *ldbwval,
                             int *nnb,
                             int *nbval,
                             int *ldnbval,
                             int *nnr,
                             int *nrval,
                             int *ldnrval,
                             int *nnbr,
                             int *nbrval,
                             int *ldnbrval,
                             int *ngrids,
                             int *pval,
                             int *ldpval,
                             int *qval,
                             int *ldqval,
                             float *thresh,
                            
                             double *work,  /* Array to gather and bcast. */
                            
                             int *iam,
                             int *nprocs);
/* http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/explore-html/dd/dad/pdgbtrf_8f.html */
extern void pdgbtrf_        (int *n,
                             int *bwl,
                             int *bwu,
                             double *a,
                             int *ja,
                             int *desca,
                             int *ipiv,
                             double *af,
                             int *laf,
                             double *work,
                             int *lwork,
                             int *info);
/* http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/explore-html/d9/dda/pdgbtrs_8f.html */
extern void pdgbtrs_        (char *trans,
                             int *n,
                             int *bwl,
                             int *bwu,
                             int *nrhs,
                             double *a,
                             int *ja,
                             int *desca,
                             int *ipiv,
                             double *b,
                             int *ib,
                             int *descb,
                             double *af,
                             int *laf,
                             double *work,
                             int *lwork,
                             int *info);
/*
http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/explore-html/d2/d66/_e_i_g_2pdmatgen_8f.html
*/
extern void pdmatgen_       (int *ictxt,
                             char *aform,
                             char *diag,
                             int *m,
                             int *n,
                             int *mb,
                             int *nb,
                             double *a,
                             int *lda,
                             int *iarow,
                             int *iacol,
                             int *iseed,
                             int *iroff,
                             int *irnum,
                             int *icoff,
                             int *icnum,
                             int *myrow,
                             int *mycol,
                             int *nprow,
                             int *npcol);
/* http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/explore-html/d2/dcd/sltimer_8f_source.html */
extern void slboot_         (void);
extern void slcombine_      (int *ictxt,
                             char *scope,
                             char *op,
                             char *timetype,
                             int *n,
                             int *ibeg,
                             double *times);
extern void sltimer_        ( int *i );

/*! External functions: */
/* http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/explore-html/d4/d48/numroc_8f.html */
extern int numroc_      (int *n,
                         int *nb,
                         int *iproc,
                         int *isrcproc,
                         int *nprocs);
/* http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/explore-html/df/dee/tools_8f.html#a67ae4efe5110e3297b1e9e3a46d8c78b */
extern logical lsame_   (char *ca,
                         char *cb);
/* http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/explore-html/db/dd0/pdlange_8f.html */
extern double pdlange_  (char *norm,
                         int *m,
                         int *n,
                         double *a,
                         int *ia,
                         int *ja,
                         int *desca,
                         double *work );

/*! Intrinsic functions: */
/*       INTRINSIC          DBLE, MAX, MIN, MOD */
inline double DBLE(int xx) { return (double) xx; }
inline double MAX(double xx, double yy) { return xx >= yy? xx: yy; }
inline double MIN(double xx, double yy) { return xx <= yy? xx: yy; }
inline int MOD(int xx, int yy) { return xx%yy; }

/*! PROGRAM PDGBDRIVER: */
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

  /*! Parameters: */
  int ntests = NTESTS;  /* Number of num. tests to be performed */
  //   int       BLOCK_CYCLIC_2D = 1;
  //   int       DTYPE_ = 1;
  //   int       CTXT_ = 2;
  //   int       M_ = 3;
  //   int       N_ = 4;
  //   int       MB_ = 5;
  //   int       NB_ = 6;
  //   int       RSRC_ = 7;
  //   int       CSRC_ = 8;
  //   int       LLD_ = 9;
  //
  //   double    ZERO = 0.0;
  //   double    PADVAL = -9923.0;
  //
  //   int       INT_ONE = 1;
  
  /*! Local scalars: */
  logical   CHECK;        /* Should or shouldn't I perform the num. tests? */
  char      TRANS;        /* Should I transpose the matrix? */
  //   char      PASSED[6];
  char      OUTFILE[80];  /* ? */
  //   int       BWL;
  //   int       BWU;
  //   int       BW_NUM;
  //   int       FILLIN_SIZE;
  //   int       FREE_PTR;
  //   int       H;
  //   int       HH;
  int       I;          /* Iterator per process grid. */
  int       IAM;          /* My MPI process ID. */
  int       IASEED;       /* Seed for random matrix A creation. */
  int       IBSEED;       /* Seed for random matrix B creation. */
  //   int       ICTXT;
  //   int       ICTXTB;
  //   int       IERR_TEMP;
  //   int       IMIDPAD;
  //   int       INFO;
  //   int       IPA;
  //   int       IPB;
  //   int       IPOSTPAD;
  //   int       IPREPAD;
  //   int       IPW;
  //   int       IPW_SIZE;
  //   int       IPW_SOLVE;
  //   int       IPW_SOLVE_SIZE;
  //   int       IP_DRIVER_W;
  //   int       IP_FILLIN;
  //   int       J;
  //   int       K;
  
  /*! Data statements: */
  //   int       KFAIL = 4;
  //   int       KPASS = 4;
  //   int       KSKIP = 4;
  //   int       KTESTS = 4;
  
  /*! Local scalars: (continued) */
  //   int       MYCOL;
  //   int       MYRHS_SIZE;
  //   int       MYROW;
  //   int       N;
  //   int       NB;
  int       NBW;    /* Number of bandwith values per matrix. */
  int       NGRIDS; /* Number of process grids to try for. */
  int       NMAT;   /* Number of matrices  */
  int       NNB;    /* Number of sizes of NB (block column size). */
  int       NNBR;
  int       NNR;
  int       NOUT;   /* Device out... o.O */
  //   int       NP;
  int       NPCOL;  /* Procs per row in processors grid/ */
  int       NPROCS; /* The size of OUR communicator. */
  //   int       NPROCS_REAL;
  int       NPROW;  /* Procs per row in processors grid/ */
  //   int       NQ;
  //   int       NRHS;
  //   int       N_FIRST;
  //   int       N_LAST;
  //   int       WORKSIZ;
  
  float     THRESH; /* Threshold variable for numerical tests. */
  
  //   double    ANORM;
  //   double    NOPS;
  //   double    NOPS2;
  //   double    SRESID;
  //   double    TMFLOPS;
  //   double    TMFLOPS2;
  
  /*! Local arrays: */
  //   int       IPIV[INTMEM];
  int       BWLVAL[NTESTS];  /* Values of lower diagonals per matrix. */
  int       BWUVAL[NTESTS];  /* Values of upper diagonals per matrix. */
  //   int       DESCA[7];
  //   int       DESCA2D[DLEN_];
  //   int       DESCB[7];
  //   int       DESCB2D[DLEN_];
  //   int       IERR[1];
  int       NBRVAL[NTESTS]; /* ? */
  int       NBVAL[NTESTS];  /* Column sizes per matrix. */
  int       NRVAL[NTESTS];  /* ? */
  int       NVAL[NTESTS];   /* Values of N for a given matrix. */
  int       PVAL[NTESTS];   /* Values for proc. rows. */
  int       QVAL[NTESTS];   /* Values for proc. cols. */
  
  //   double    CTIME[2];
  double    *MEM;      /* GLOABL array for broadcasting the information. */
  //   double    WTIME[2];

  /*! Executable statements: */

  /*! Get starting information: */
  Cblacs_pinfo(&IAM, &NPROCS);
  IASEED = 100;
  IBSEED = 200;

  MEM = (double *) malloc(MEMSIZ);
  
  pdgbinfo_(OUTFILE, &NOUT, &TRANS, &NMAT, NVAL, &ntests, &NBW,
            BWLVAL, BWUVAL, &ntests, &NNB, NBVAL, &ntests, &NNR,
            NRVAL, &ntests, &NNBR, NBRVAL, &ntests, &NGRIDS, PVAL,
            &ntests, QVAL, &ntests, &THRESH, MEM, &IAM, &NPROCS);

  CHECK = (THRESH >= 0.0f);

  /*! Print headings: */
  fprintf(stdout, "\n");
  fprintf(stdout, "TIME TR      N  BWL BWU    NB  NRHS    P    Q L*U Time Slv Time   MFLOPS   MFLOP2  CHECK\n");
  fprintf(stdout, "---- -- ------  --- ---  ---- ----- ---- ---- -------- -------- -------- -------- ------\n");
  fprintf(stdout, "\n");
  fflush(stdout);

  /*! Loop over different process grids: */
  for (I = 1; I <= NGRIDS; I++) {

    NPROW = PVAL[I - 1];
    NPCOL = QVAL[I - 1];

    fprintf(stdout, "Solving for a %d x %d grid!\n", NPROW, NPCOL);
  }

  free(MEM);
  Cblacs_exit(0);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Please excuse the amount of commented-out variables, but like I said, I am basically translating the reference driver, from scratch.

My problem is that it suddenly started seg-faulting, as soon as I wrote the for loop... it was working before. That is a clear sign of a funky memory manipulation issue, which probably arises from issues related to the memory management differences between C and Fortran.

At least, that is my guess.

Does anybody has a clue on what may be going wrong?

Comment: The wonderful f2c exists for this task. Use it with the -a switch and it is all good.

Comment: `for (I = 1; I <= NGRIDS; I++) {

    NPROW = PVAL[I - 1];
    NPCOL = QVAL[I - 1];

    fprintf(stdout, "Solving for a %d x %d grid!\n", NPROW, NPCOL);
  }` suggests that there could be more 1-offset problems hidden under the hood. Numerical Recipes revisited... And the CAPSONLY is horrible.

Comment: Dear David, thanks for your recommendation, I will take a look at that.

Comment: Dear "wildplasser", the seg-fault persists even by removing that loop. I do not understand what you mean with "suggests that there could be more 1-offset problems hidden under the hood. Numerical Recipes revisited...". Furthermore, the only reason I go with "CAPSONLY" is to make it more familiar to the code I want to duplicate. In conclusion, I understood 0% of your reply. Nonetheless, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read from your code, you are never actually checking the value of `NGRIDS`.
my guess is that it's too large and the array indices go beyond limits.

Comment: Dear Andreas,

you are right. My problem is that, even when I remove that loop, the seg-fault persists. Please see [ http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/155238-greetings-my-first-post-c-fotran-hybrid-code-using-mpi-scalapack-seg-faults-weird.html#post1154687 ] for a discussion in a more friendly environment.

Answer (score 7):

Here the fundamental issue is actually in the call to `pdgbinfo`, which was never really meant to be called from C (it's in TESTING, after all); the issue is the strings, which are in fact passed differently from the numeric arrays -- lengths are always passed (so that you can print them, for instance).

You can mock that up on the C side, but it'll be highly compiler dependent.   Your best bet is to either pull the strings out of those routines, or to use [ISO_C_BINDING](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ISO_005fC_005fBINDING.html) to generate portable C interfaces to the relevant fortran routines.   Routines with purely numerical arrays in F77 code shouldn't be an issue.

**Updated**:  If you change the beginning of `pdgbinfo.f` and the subroutine declaration like so:

```
      SUBROUTINE PDGBINFO(CSUMMRY, NOUT, TRANS, NMAT, NVAL, LDNVAL, NBW,
     &                     BWLVAL, BWUVAL, LDBWVAL, NNB, NBVAL, LDNBVAL,
     &                     NNR, NRVAL, LDNRVAL, NNBR, NBRVAL, LDNBRVAL,
     &                     NGRIDS, PVAL, LDPVAL, QVAL, LDQVAL, THRESH,
     &                     WORK, IAM, NPROCS ) BIND(C)

      use iso_c_binding
      implicit none
*
*
*
*  -- ScaLAPACK routine (version 1.7) --
*     University of Tennessee, Knoxville, Oak Ridge National Laboratory,
*     and University of California, Berkeley.
*     November 15, 1997
*
*     .. Scalar Arguments ..
      CHARACTER(kind=c_char), intent(OUT) :: TRANS
      CHARACTER(kind=c_char), dimension(*), intent(OUT) :: CSUMMRY
      INTEGER(kind=c_int), intent(IN)     :: IAM, LDNVAL, LDNBVAL,
     &                                       LDNRVAL, LDNBRVAL, LDPVAL,
     &                                       LDBWVAL, LDQVAL

      INTEGER(kind=c_int), intent(INOUT)  :: NPROCS

      INTEGER(kind=c_int), intent(OUT)    :: NOUT, NMAT, NBW, NNB,
     &                                       NNR, NNBR, NGRIDS

      REAL(kind=c_float), intent(OUT)     :: THRESH

      INTEGER(kind=c_int), intent(OUT) ::  NBRVAL( LDNBRVAL ),
     &                   NBVAL( LDNBVAL ),
     &                   NRVAL( LDNRVAL ), NVAL( LDNVAL ),
     &                   BWLVAL( LDBWVAL),BWUVAL( LDBWVAL),
     &                   PVAL( LDPVAL ), QVAL(LDQVAL), WORK( * )

      CHARACTER(kind=c_char,len=100) :: SUMMRY
      INTEGER :: c,sumlen
```

And then change where it reads the file to copy the string into the C-array:

```
*
*        Read name and unit number for summary output file
*
         READ( NIN, FMT = * ) SUMMRY
** convert to C string
         sumlen = len_trim(SUMMRY)
         do c=1,sumlen
            csummry(c) = summry(c:c)
         enddo
         csummry(sumlen+1) = c_null_char
```

You should then be able to get rid of the underscores after `pdgbinfo` in your C program and have it work in a way that's portable across compiler suites.

Comment: Dear Jonathan Dursi,

thanks! I will take a look at that... have you ever tried f2c? Thanks!

Comment: Yes; it really only works reliably on code that's simple enough that you don't need to use it.  You could try running it on pdgbinfo.f, but I'd be very surprised if it got the string-handling right for an arbitrary compiler.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the correct `iso_c_binding` usage to be able to more portably call `pdgbinfo` from C.

Comment: @JonathanDursi Nonsense!! It ports from Fortran to C far more accurately than a human does. If you can use it doing so will reduce the chance of you making mistakes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Even better is not porting at all by creating the C binding for the fortran routine. It's trivial now, as shown above, and you can even just add a wrapper if you don't want to touch the original code. f2c is much more delicate, translating only from a subset of f77 to C and making assumptions about the underlying compiler. Should the OP f2c just pdgbinfo.f, or all of Scalapack? Will it work linking against the Intel MKL's implementation of scalapack, or only those compiled with similar compilers? The above solution works and is portable so it will stay working.

Comment: @JonathanDursi I totally agree for larger works. But if you want to use a very limited set of code then f2c can be useful. In my situation I'm statically linked .obj files and my linker is fussy about the format. I also have no knowledge of Fortran at all. So it's very effective for me to pipe the simple F77 routines through `f2c -a` and let my C compiler do the rest. That's better than manual ports. But yes, I do recognise that I'm in something of a minority position. FWIW, I think the first sentence of your very good answer (+1) is needlessly confrontational.

Comment: @JonathanDursi Thank you very much. It's 9:00 AM here in San Diego! I will take a shower, go to my office and give this a try! Can't wait!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - FWIW, the comment wasn't directed at you, but you're quite right and I've deleted it.  And you're also right that f2c has its place.

Comment: @JonathanDursi: Hi! I've tried modifying PDGBINFO:

[ejspeiro@node01 LIN]$ make
mpif90 -c -g pdgbinfo.f
 In file pdgbinfo.f:5

     &                     WORK, IAM, NPROCS ) BIND(C)                  
                                             1
Error: Syntax error in SUBROUTINE statement at (1)
 In file pdgbinfo.f:7

      use iso_c_binding                                                 
                                                                       1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'iso_c_binding.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
make: *** [pdgbinfo.o] Error 1

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Quick question... I have been trying to ind how to make f2c not adding a second '_' when translating this code (I'm trying both your f2c option and Jonathan's option)... thus my question: how can I have f2c bot adding the second '_'; i.e. to generate "blacs_pinfo_" instead of "blacs_pinfo__"? Thanks!

Comment: @EduardoSanchez : The first guess is that you're using a quite old compiler (gfortran, maybe, from the wording of the message?  Maybe 4.2, which was still the default in RHEL/Centos/Scientific Linux 5?).   What is the output of `mpif90 -v`?

Comment: @JonathanDursi: [ejspeiro@node01 LIN]$ mpif90 -v
mpif90 for the Intel(R) MPI Library 3.2 for Linux
Driving: gfortran -v -I/opt/intel/impi/3.2.0.011/include64/gfortran/4.1.0 -I/opt/intel/impi/3.2.0.011/include64 -L/opt/intel/impi/3.2.0.011/lib64 -Xlinker --enable-new-dtags -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /opt/intel/impi/3.2.0.011/lib64 -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /opt/intel/mpi-rt/3.2 -lmpi -lmpigf -lmpigi -lrt -lpthread -ldl -lgfortranbegin -lgfortran -lm -shared-libgcc
Using built-in specs.

Comment: @JonathanDursi: Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --disable-plugin --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/jre --with-cpu=generic --host=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix

Comment: @JonathanDursi: gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/collect2 --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/crtbegin.o -L/opt/intel/impi/3.2.0.011/lib64 -L/app/intel/mkl/10.1.0.015/lib/em64t -L/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/083/ipp/em64t/lib

Comment: @JonathanDursi: -L/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/083/mkl/lib/em64t -L/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/083/tbb/em64t/cc4.1.0_libc2.4_kernel2.6.16.21/lib -L/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/083/ipp/em64t/lib -L/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/083/mkl/lib/em64t -L/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/083/tbb/em64t/cc4.1.0_libc2.4_kernel2.6.16.21/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 --enable-new-dtags -rpath /opt/intel/impi/3.2.0.011/lib64

Comment: @JonathanDursi: -rpath /opt/intel/mpi-rt/3.2 -lmpi -lmpigf -lmpigi -lrt -lpthread -ldl -lgfortranbegin -lgfortran -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/libgfortranbegin.a(fmain.o): In function `main':
(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `MAIN__'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
[ejspeiro@node01 LIN]$

Comment: Yeah, ok, so gfortran 4.1.2 is a little over 6 years old now, and there are a lot of important features and bug fixes it doesn't have.  Is using the still-old-but-much-newer intel v11 compilers you seem to have installed an option?   Or even just a newer gfortran (4.3 or later?)

Comment: @JonathanDursi: Good question! Good thing my advisor is root in this cluster. I will ask him in our meeting, an hour from now! Thanks! PS: Are you going to SC13 next November? :)

Comment: For what is worth it, the f2c output for this problem, does NOT work: Floating Exception rank 0 in job 1  node01-10gbase-cx4_38381 caused collective abort of all ranks exit status of rank 0: killed by signal 6

Comment: @JonathanDursi: Hello! I finally gave myself the time to implement the modifications on PDGBINFO, based on using the ISO C BINDING. Here are my modifications:

      SUBROUTINE PDGBINFO( CSUMMRY, NOUT, TRANS, NMAT, NVAL, LDNVAL, NBW,
     $                     BWLVAL, BWUVAL, LDBWVAL, NNB, NBVAL, LDNBVAL,
     $                     NNR, NRVAL, LDNRVAL, NNBR, NBRVAL, LDNBRVAL,
     $                     NGRIDS, PVAL, LDPVAL, QVAL, LDQVAL, THRESH,
     $                     WORK, IAM, NPROCS ) BIND(C)

     use iso_c_binding
     implicit none

Comment: @JonathanDursi: I better list the modifications as another answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here the suggested modifications:

```
      SUBROUTINE PDGBINFO( CSUMMRY, NOUT, TRANS, NMAT, NVAL, LDNVAL, NBW,
 $                     BWLVAL, BWUVAL, LDBWVAL, NNB, NBVAL, LDNBVAL,
 $                     NNR, NRVAL, LDNRVAL, NNBR, NBRVAL, LDNBRVAL,
 $                     NGRIDS, PVAL, LDPVAL, QVAL, LDQVAL, THRESH,
 $                     WORK, IAM, NPROCS ) BIND(C)
*
 use iso_c_binding
 implicit none
*
*     .. Scalar Arguments ..
  CHARACTER(kind=c_char), intent(out) :: TRANS
  CHARACTER(kind=c_char), dimension(*), intent(OUT) :: CSUMMRY
  INTEGER(kind=c_int), intent(in) :: IAM, LDNVAL, LDNBVAL,
 $                                   LDNRVAL, LDNBRVAL, LDPVAL,
 $                                   LDBWVAL, LDQVAL
 INTEGER(kind=c_int), intent(inout) :: NPROCS
 INTEGER(kind=c_int), intent(out) :: NOUT, NMAT, NBW, NNB,
 $                                   NNR, NNBR, NGRIDS
 REAL(KIND=C_FLOAT), intent(out) :: THRESH
*     ..
*     .. Array Arguments ..
  INTEGER(kind=c_int), intent(out) :: NBRVAL( LDNBRVAL ), NBVAL( LDNBVAL ),
 $                   NRVAL( LDNRVAL ), NVAL( LDNVAL ),
 $                   BWLVAL( LDBWVAL), BWUVAL( LDBWVAL),
 $                   PVAL( LDPVAL ), QVAL(LDQVAL), WORK( * )

 CHARACTER(KIND=c_char,len=100) :: SUMMRY
 INTEGER :: c, sumlen
```

Yet those yield the following compiling-time error:

```
[ejspeiro@node01 LIN]$ mpif90 -c -O3 pdgbinfo.f
pdgbinfo.f:5.54:

     $                     WORK, IAM, NPROCS ) BIND(C)                  
                                                      1
Error: Syntax error in SUBROUTINE statement at (1)
pdgbinfo.f:18.21:

      CHARACTER(kind=c_char), intent(out) :: TRANS                      
                     1
Error: Parameter 'c_char' at (1) has not been declared or is a variable, which does not reduce to a constant expression
```

Plus a few more!

Once again:

```
[ejspeiro@node01 LIN]$ mpif90 -v
mpif90 for the Intel(R) MPI Library 3.2 for Linux
Driving: gfortran -v -I/opt/intel/impi/3.2.0.011/include64/gfortran/4.1.0 -I/opt/intel/impi/3.2.0.011/include64 -L/opt/intel/impi/3.2.0.011/lib64 -Xlinker --enable-new-dtags -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /opt/intel/impi/3.2.0.011/lib64 -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /opt/intel/mpi-rt/3.2 -lmpi -lmpigf -lmpigi -lrt -lpthread -ldl -lgfortranbegin -lgfortran -lm -shared-libgcc
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux6E
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --disable-gnu-unique-object --with-as=/usr/libexec/binutils220/as --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --disable-libgcj --with-mpfr=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.4.7-20120601/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux6E/mpfr-install/ --with-ppl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.4.7-20120601/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux6E/ppl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.4.7-20120601/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux6E/cloog-install --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i586 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux6E
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1) (GCC) 
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.7/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.7/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.7/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/:/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/../lib64/:/app/intel/mkl/10.1.0.015/lib/em64t/:/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/083/ipp/em64t/lib/:/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/083/mkl/lib/em64t/:/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/083/tbb/em64t/cc4.1.0_libc2.4_kernel2.6.16.21/lib/:/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/083/ipp/em64t/lib/:/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/083/mkl/lib/em64t/:/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/083/tbb/em64t/cc4.1.0_libc2.4_kernel2.6.16.21/lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.7/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-I/opt/intel/impi/3.2.0.011/include64/gfortran/4.1.0' '-I/opt/intel/impi/3.2.0.011/include64' '-L/opt/intel/impi/3.2.0.011/lib64' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.7/collect2 --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.7/crtbegin.o -L/opt/intel/impi/3.2.0.011/lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.7 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.7 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.7/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/app/intel/mkl/10.1.0.015/lib/em64t -L/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/083/ipp/em64t/lib -L/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/083/mkl/lib/em64t -L/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/083/tbb/em64t/cc4.1.0_libc2.4_kernel2.6.16.21/lib -L/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/083/ipp/em64t/lib -L/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/083/mkl/lib/em64t -L/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/083/tbb/em64t/cc4.1.0_libc2.4_kernel2.6.16.21/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.7/../../.. --enable-new-dtags -rpath /opt/intel/impi/3.2.0.011/lib64 -rpath /opt/intel/mpi-rt/3.2 -lmpi -lmpigf -lmpigi -lrt -lpthread -ldl -lgfortranbegin -lgfortran -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.7/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.7/libgfortranbegin.a(fmain.o): In function `main':
(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `MAIN__'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```